# Wallaby.js support for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, wallaby.js

I am looking for Wallaby.js support for Eclipse. While the [official page](http://wallabyjs.com/) lists JetBrains IDEs, Visual Studio and Atom Editor, there is no mention of Eclipse. Has anyone integrated / used Wallaby.js with Eclipse ?

Comment: Wallaby.js founder's here. There're no close plans to support Eclipse in wallaby.js.

Comment: Thanks for the reply